# How to create a Graph of Mathematica Commands of the installed version

Tags: graphs-and-networks, notebooks, built-in-symbols

I always wonder how many inbuilt functions does Mathematica have (of course you can google for it) and how they are connected with each other! So I tried this (v10.1).

```
SetDirectory[$InstallationDirectory<>"/Documentation/English/System/ReferencePages/Symbols"]
comms = FileNames[];
ncomms = Length[comms]
```

> 4613

I believe this is the total number of documented functions. Now the second part where I am stuck in. **How to find the connections among them?**

What I am thinking is to get the list of functions from the `See Also` section of an example. Here I do one manually. Let's say I start with `Plot`. `See Also` in `Plot.nb` contains ({DiscretePlot, ListLinePlot, ParametricPlot, PolarPlot, Plot3D, ContourPlot, Graphics, Show}). So I store them.

```
link["Plot"] = {"DiscretePlot", "ListLinePlot", "ParametricPlot" , 
                "PolarPlot", "Plot3D", "ContourPlot", "Graphics", "Show"};
```

Now I want to scan each element of the list. For example, I take `Plot3D` and `Graphics`

```
link["Plot3D"] = {"ListPlot3D", "ContourPlot", "DensityPlot", "ParametricPlot3D",
                  "Graphics3D", "ListSurfacePlot3D", "Plot", "Show"};

link["Graphics"] = {"Plot", "ListPlot", "ListLinePlot", "ParametricPlot", "DensityPlot",
                    "ArrayPlot", "RegionPlot", "ContourPlot", "Show", "Graphics3D",
                    "Image", "Import", "Sound"};
```

Now combine and map them

```
map = Join[DirectedEdge[num["Plot"], num[#]] & /@ link["Plot"],
           DirectedEdge[num["Plot3D"], num[#]] & /@ link["Plot3D"],
           DirectedEdge[num["Graphics"], num[#]] & /@ link["Graphics"]];

Graph[map, VertexLabels -> Table[n -> sets[[n]], {n, nsets}], ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image]

**How can I put this whole thing in a Mathematica code?**

Comment: You can start with: `WolframLanguageData["Plot", "RelationshipCommunityGraph"]`

Comment: closely related: [How to get complete Documentation Center graph of guide pages?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8505/5478)

Comment: thanks @Kuba, didn't know about `WolframLanguageData`. I like Leonid's answer because it will work for the older version as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
(* docs on my system (10.3, Windows) *)
base = FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "Documentation",
    "English", "System", "ReferencePages", "Symbols"}];

FileNames[FileNameJoin[{base, "*"}]] // Length
```

> 4811

```
(* symbols in See Also section *)
also[name_String] :=
 Module[{import},
  import = Import[
    FileNameJoin[{base, name <> ".nb"}], {"Cells", "SeeAlso"}];
  Cases[import, TextData[s_String] :> s, Infinity]]

also["I"]
```

> {"Complex", "Re", "Im", "ComplexExpand", "GaussianIntegers"}

```
edges[start_String, n_Integer] :=
 Reap[Module[{visited = {}},
     Nest[
      Function[visiting,
       Module[{temp},
        temp = Join @@ Table[
           Sow[DirectedEdge[v, #] & /@ also[v]], {v, visiting}];
        visited = Join[visited, visiting];
        Complement[Last /@ temp, visited]]],
      {start}, n]]][[2, 1]] // Flatten

graph[edges : {__DirectedEdge}, start_String, opts___] :=
 Graph[edges, opts,
  VertexLabels -> "Name",
  VertexStyle -> {start -> Red}]
```

### Example 1

```
With[{x = "I"}, graph[edges[x, 2], x]]
```

[image]

### Example 2

```
(* this took me 40 seconds *)
e5 = edges["Plot", 5];

g = graph[e5, "Plot",
  VertexLabels -> None,
  EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.2]],
  EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Arrowheads[.01], Arrow[#]} &)];

Through[{VertexCount, EdgeCount}@g]
```

> {1463, 4192}

Majority of vertices are not reachable from a general source (dark red area). Note that: a) graph is directed, and b) crawler stopped after five steps.

```
dm = GraphDistanceMatrix[g];
dm // MatrixPlot
```

[image]

```
max = Max[dm /. Infinity -> 0]
```

> 13

```
pos = Position[dm, max];
pairs = VertexList[g][[#]] & /@ pos;
```

Example of a longest shortest path (via `pairs`). Starting in Help with `Repeated`, 13 clicks are needed at least to get to `Arrow`.

```
sp = FindShortestPath[g, "Repeated", "Arrow"];
(* {"Repeated", "BlankSequence", ... "Arrow"} *)

HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph[sp, DirectedEdges -> True]]
```

[image]

Comment: This method is awesome! In lots of aspects it's better than mine! would you mind me to edit my answer a bit to include some awesome part of your answer? (like `Import` stuff)

Comment: Also, this method has one small drawback in the crawler part: you actually can store something to aviod repetitive calculation and import. This may speed things up a lot I suppose? :)

Comment: @Wjx No, I wouldn't mind, and yes, I've been thinking about the crawler ... will update.

Comment: However, [result for cosine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/erzLw.png) is nothing like `WolframLanguageData` [example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UGNjA.png).

Comment: I've consolidated the code and added an example.

Comment: that's wonderful @BoLe . Now I am going to run it on different versions of MMA and see their viral growth :)

Comment: @Sumit Counting `System` symbols: `Length[Names["System\`*"]]` gives me 5645, version 11 would return 5900, and version 3: 1527.

Comment: @BoLe, Spoiler alert. Besides, I don't think `System` is a good choice. If you check ``SetDirectory[base];Complement[Names["System`*"],StringDrop[#, -3] & /@ FileNames[]]`` , you will see that they don't give functions. They are more like options MMA use itself.

Comment: @Sumit Oh, sorry. You're probably right, the complement is meant mostly for internal use. Though one can readily use `SequenceLimit` for example, it has even `SequenceLimit::usage` defined.

Answer (score 8):

There is a way for you to find out the relations without internet, and I think it fit your need more as they are actually extracted directly from those "See Also" links.

I'm currently using v11, 5000+ Functions, it takes about 7 min before it finishes the main evaluation, and another 10 min or so for plotting the community graph out, but it's totally internet free, thus can be a bit more helpful when under bad net conditions.

```
dir = FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, 
    "Documentation\\English\\System\\ReferencePages\\Symbols"}];
files = Import[dir];

rules = Flatten[Function[{name}, Thread[StringSplit[name, "."][[1]] -> 
   Block[{f = Import[FileNameJoin[{dir, name}]], p}, 
    p = Position[f, "See Also"]; 
     If[p != {}, Cases[#, TextData[s_String]:>s] &@
      Extract[f, Drop[p[[-1]], -5]], {}]]]] /@ files];

Graph@rules
CommunityGraphPlot@%
```

This method follows how we humans know about the links between functions-----via checking the "See Also" part of the documentation of course. So we can extract those part out one by one, make rules out of them, then use `Graph` and `CommunityGraphPlot` to visualize them.

The result is stylish(If we view in the Abstract Painting's style :P) and the structure is clear(Though a bit messy): Mathematica's core functions are closely related!!!

[image: graph]

[image: community graph]

Comment: Thanks @Wjx, I am indeed looking for a method which does not involve the internet. I added that to the title.

Comment: So will this be what you need? @Sumit :)

Comment: yup. I will accept it few hours later - just in case someone has some other thoughts ;)

Comment: I was wondering whether the complete relationship was connected, as in a single component graph ... Did you identify some of the symbols in other components?

Comment: [ImageIdentify](https://www.imageidentify.com/) thinks that these graphs are [a virus](https://www.imageidentify.com/result/1jcgosyaptzo6) and [a bobby pin](https://www.imageidentify.com/result/077v2aeqo6xrt), respectively.

Comment: @Karsten7. That's a proper result! :P

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```
g = SimpleGraph@Graph[
    Catenate[
     Thread /@ 
      Normal@DeleteMissing@
        WolframLanguageData[WolframLanguageData[], "RelatedSymbols", "EntityAssociation"]
     ],
    DirectedEdges -> False
    ];
```

It's slow, like most new `*Data` functions, but it works.

Comment: You can get a bunch of smaller graphs that show some connections with `WolframLanguageData[All, "RelationshipGraph"]` -- so not exactly what the OP asked for but interesting visualisations anyway. It doesn't have all the functions (`WLD[f, "RelationshipGraph"]` doesn't show `f` in its graph). Makes for a nice puzzle, as well...